# Is it possible to create by Applescript a new Illustrator document with other name than Untitled-*?

Tags: illustrator-scripting

I've tried this applescript code for Illustrator CS6:

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
 make document with properties {name:"anyName"}
end tell
```

but couldn't affect the name of newly created doc.
I do can create layers with any name I want, but the document itself not.

Is it 100% impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer in Adobe Scripting Guide -

"the name property of the document object in most Adobe applications is read-only; therefore, you cannot use a script to define or change the name of an existing document (although you can use a save as command or method"

thus, I cannot create a new document with a particular name using applescript, however I can "name" it by using SaveAs option...